# Sorting a Column(PANCARD)Values in Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Column in `dataframe` called `PANCARD`.

PANCARD Values are:
    DEAS1067SS | BEAT1123Z

And I want `PANCARD` values to be Sorted like below:

```
0167ADESS
1123ABETZ
```

Please help!

I am Doing `DF.sort($PANCARD)`, but this is not working

**Actual Values:**

```
DEAS1067S | BEAT1123Z
```

**Expected Values:**

```
0167ADESS | 1123ABETZ
```

Comment: what is the logic for sorting? alphanumeric or some pattern?

Comment: there is no such pattern, all string should be sorted

Comment: val val v = "BEAT1120Z" val sortedValue = v.map(_.toInt).sorted.map(.toChar).mkString("") This does the sorting but i guess i've to write a UDF to do it on a Column

Answer (score 2):

Finally Written the UDF Function.

```
val sortedValue: String => String =_.map(_.toInt).sorted.map(_.toChar).mkString("")

import org.apache.spark.sql.function.udf

val sortedUdf = udf(sortedValue)

df.withColumn("PANCARD", sortedUdf(col("PANCARD")))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try by converting column to a String in map function and re-create a dataframe again.

````
val result = DF.map(r => { val x = r.getAs[String]("pancard")
val y = x.split(" ").map(_.sorted).mkString(" ")
Row(r(0),y) })

val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result, DF.schema) ```
````